# Inject angular component into a chrome extension content script

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am developing a a chrome extension that modifies the DOM of the page using content scripts. This is all fine if I stick to HTML, CSS, javascript. However, I'd like to leverage the power of Angular 7. Because of the bootstrapping process I am not sure how I can inject app components into a page.

I'll try to make this more concrete with an example.

Say I have a [modal component](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview). How can I configure the `manifest.json` and `angular.json` files to inject my component dynamically every time someone highlights some text in the page (for example).

I'm ok fiddling with Webpack configuration options or other no-standard thing to be able to leverage Angular in the extension.

I could find a few tutorials explaining it for react (for example [here](https://itnext.io/create-chrome-extension-with-reactjs-using-inject-page-strategy-137650de1f39)). Is there an equivalent for Angular?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.