# How can I import html file into the function of typescript file?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension

How can I import html file into the function of typescript file?

I am creating chrome extension using Angular and I am facing an issue to import html into the function of ts file.

I have login.component.ts file.
There is one function, name is init().

This init() function will be called from some another file let's say it's content-script.js (which is in root and it'll be call every time when page is reload/chrome extension will attach).

I have another file login.component.html.

I want to attach my login html in div classes of some website. So i will fetch that div classes from the website and have to attach this login html file into that div classes.

For ex.
content-script.ts

```
import {LoginComponent} from './app/user/login.component'
var loginComponent : LoginComponent = new LoginComponent();
loginComponent.init();
```

login.component.ts

```
@Component({ 
selector: 'app-login', 
templateUrl: './login.component.html', 
styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit { 
init() => { 
let element = 'here we need templateUrl which is login.component.html' 
$('.my-website-class> div > div > .tempclass').last().after(element);
 }
}
```

login.components.html

```
<div>Attach this login html file into the login component ts file</div>
```

This "element" should be my login.component.html file.
So How can i fetch this html/templateUrl file into ts file and attach it with website's div?
In Angular js, we were using something like this.

```
var loginButtonTemplate = require('./login_button.html');
 
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
var loginButton = $compile(loginButtonTemplate)(scope);
$('.my-website-class> div > div > .tempclass').last().after(loginButton);
```

Thank you!

Comment: What you want to achieve seems to be going against angular framework. Let angular decide when and where to inject/render a html template based on the component selector. Do something like `<div class="tempclass"><app-login></app-login></div>`. Let the framework take care of this stuff. If you want to control this through JS, you don't need to use angular.

Comment: @zermelozf did you find any solution for this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754377/inject-angular-component-into-a-chrome-extension-content-script

I am looking solution for the similar issue which you have also raised on the past.